# Constraint a table to not have more than 2 rows with the same foreign key id

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

i got table `teams` with `team_id primary key` and the table `pilots` with foreign key `team_id`. I want to apply a constraint that won't let me add more than 2 pilots with the same `team_id`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to count the number of pilots for the specific team_id, then check against the function in a constraint.

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnHowManyPilots(@team_id INT)  
RETURNS int  
AS   
BEGIN  
   DECLARE @pilot_count int
   SELECT @pilot_count = COUNT(*)
   FROM pilots
   WHERE team_id = @team_id
   RETURN @pilot_count
END;
```

Then add a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE pilots  
ADD CONSTRAINT chkPilotCount CHECK (dbo.FnHowManyPilots(team_id) <= 2 );  
GO
```